# Swift help for a newbie

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error message and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.  This is my first program and don't know too much on how to debug it.

Error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
            var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
        } else {
            println("file path is empty")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value of `filePathUrl` is non-nil before using it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)` returns an Optional value which could potentially be nil. You should check before using it:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
    if let filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath) {
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
    }
} else {
    println("file path is empty")
}
```

Comment: ```if var ...``` is legitimate, but ```if let ...``` is a better choice in most cases

Comment: @bolot I've never seen `if var ...` in official doc. Don't know it's actually legit. Anyway, it's definitely not the best practice.

Comment: From Apple document on Swift:  "You can use both constants and variables with optional binding. If you wanted to manipulate the value of actualNumber within the first branch of the if statement, you could write if var actualNumber instead, and the value contained within the optional would be made available as a variable rather than a constant."  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for the reference. Guess I'm just making a careless mistake.

Comment: @Sw At which line did `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb) ` happen?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you've declared the variable audioPlayer `var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!` The exclamation mark means that it can't be nil when unwrapped.

So, in this code:

```
if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
    var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
} else {
   println("file path is empty")
}
```

You've got a variable called `filePathUrl`. That variable is using `NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)`. This can return `nil`. If it does, then your variable `filePathUrl` is nil. Then when you use that in `audioPlayer`, it's nil, so `audioPlayer` returns nil.

But remember, `audioPlayer` has a `!`. It can't be nil. So what you can do (simplest option), is to have an extra if statement:

```
if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
   if let filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath) {
       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
   }
} else {
   println("file path is empty")
}
```

This extra if statement double checks that `filePathUrl` isn't nil. If it is, it sends the program to the else statement. If it isn't nil, then it allows `audioPlayer` to do its thing. And, because we know the value isn't nil, audioPlayer won't return an error.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is most likely happening when you tap a button and the `playSlowAudio` function gets called.

The problem is you are using an implicitly unwrapped optional for `audioPlayer`. If the initialization of the player failed (for example, file wasn't found), then `audioPlayer` will be `nil`. So when the button action is called, `audioPlayer.stop()` attempt to unwrap `audioPlayer` before calling `stop()`, which causes the crash.

To fix, change `audioPlayer` to be a regular optional:

`var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?`

And use it with the safer optional chaining:

`audioPlayer?.stop()`

So the full example will look like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class PlaySoundsViewController: UIViewController {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("crankringtone", ofType: "mp3"){
            var filePathUrl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)

            audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: filePathUrl, error: nil)
        } else {
            println("file path is empty")
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func playSlowAudio(sender: UIButton) {
        audioPlayer?.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: I had a wrong mp3 file name there earlier – was that the problem?

Comment: Are you still getting the crash? Or is it just not functioning?

Comment: no crash.  it is just not functioning.  i put println's all over and confirmed that the audioPlayer is not getting created.